# PLC/Modbus read coil status (modbus tk)

Tags: python, modbus, plc

Hopefully there is a bored PLC modbus expert out there who needs some entertainment.. I'm going crazy trying to figure this out.

I'm trying to read the status of the output coils Q1 to Q8 on a teco SG2 20VR-D.

I'm using Modbus-TK in python and I can easily communicate with the plc to write to coils, read registers etc. But I can't figure out how the heck to read the output coils Q1-Q8 so I can check their status.

The address table is on page 29/31 of the attached PDF.  My unit is a V3 type.

If you read the small print on page 29 there is some cryptic message about multiplying by 10h???? help!

When I use this command I get a simple tuple with a zero for the only value.

```
slave_address = 1

command = 1 #read coils

coil_address = 11312 # this is 2c30h converted to decimal.  2c30h is the address for Q1 according to the pdf

master.execute(slave_address, command, coil_address)
```

(when I evaluate the expression in Pycharm.. this what I get)
Returns:

```
result = {tuple} <type 'tuple'>:()
__len__ = {int} 0
```

The trouble is Q1 is energized (closed) so it should show 1 or 65280 not 0, so this can't be right.

Should I be using some kind of range for the coil addresses?  Can anyone explain how this should be done?

[Teco SG3 Modbus Manual](http://www.bb-elec.com/Products/Manuals/SG2_V-typeModbusProtocol_0807.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all familiar with what you're doing, but a quick look at the docs shows that you're not specifying all the needed parameters for the READ_COILS command - there's also a "quantity_of_x" parameter (number of coils to read, for this particular command), that modbus-tk defaults to 0.  So, you're requesting the values of a total of zero coils, which exactly matches the results you got.  This parameter apparently needs to be a multiple of 0x10, so you'd have to request more than just the Q1-Q8 values - the other eight values would be garbage.

Comment: thanks... where did you find the documentation for modbus-tk.. I have been looking high and low for good documentation and couldn't find it.

Comment: I didn't see any standalone documentation, but there are docstrings in the source itself that I found at https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/master/modbus_tk/modbus.py

Comment: Requiring the number of coils to be a multiple of 16 is awkward, non-standard behavior. Anyway, this is Modbus, each implementation has its quirks. Just use 16 as the number of coils and it should work,

Answer (score 0):

"01H: user set the start address equal multiple of 10H, and quantity of coils also equal multiple of 10H"

Modbus implementations typically expect either a full register value (what you are using I think) OR an offset. Did you try getting to the offset in this case by multiplying the base register by 16 (10h)?

Did you try looking at the outgoing and incoming messages for clues? Wireshark will automatically break down Modbus messages for you.

I don't have a direct answer for you, with a lot of this stuff you have to dive into it yourself since every modbus implementation is a little different.

I don't know your skill level but I would start by forensically picking apart the message (the bytes) in wireshark to figure out exactly what the device is returning and verify what you are sending. This information may also help:

http://support.autosoln.com/support/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/63/0/modbus-protocol-overview-debugging-your-acm-configuration-by-dissecting-modbus-messages